# Update uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy to io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:

Tags: android, calligraphy

I had before uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0. After updated to io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1 I can't find CalligraphyContextWrapper class, the code below:

```
    protected void attachBaseContext(final Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I need to use ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap instead of CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap.
ViewPumpContextWrapper can be found in io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3 library.